# How do I enable my following code to work on GitHub and make the site show?

Tags: javascript, web, github, web-development-server

I have a repository on GitHub which has various folders and files.
But when I click at the published site link, the site doesn't work. It doesn't open.
I thought this had something to do with the extensions of my files imported from Javascript that used "./" extension from the base folder up to the file to be chosen. I did this for all the imported files. But the site doesn't open and a page showing the Readme text shows upon clicking the URL.
What do you think might be the problem?

Below is part of the code and how I referenced to the files.

```
        import Layout from './src/components/Layout';
        import Container from './src/components/Container';
        import Map from './src/components/Map';
```

Comment: Have you checked what dev tools says?
Do you know that you have to build the website? Imports doesn't work in browser out of the box.

Comment: can you mention what js framework are you using. usually they need to be generated ti html files to be accessible on the web

Comment: I am using gatsby-starter-leaflet framework.